# Extract git subdirectory while keeping history WITH renames

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm splitting a big source tree into two separate components and a shared submodule.  In order to prepare for this split, I first moved the shared stuff into a single "common" directory, updated all the references, and made a commit.  So far so good.  Now I'd like to extract that directory into a submodule.

Normally I'd do this with

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter
```

But in this case, all the interesting history happened outside that subdirectory, so the history gets lost.

I understand that it doesn't make sense to keep the full history, since that wouldn't be filtering out any data at all.  But I'm not really going for the ability to go back in time and build, I just want to be able to look at the commits each file was a member of.

Is there a way to keep the filter-branch behavior while keeping the history of the individual files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. `--subdirectory-filter` is a bit of a special case in that it's actually modifying the contents of trees significantly (since it's moving things up one or more directory nesting levels).

As such, there's not really a good mapping between files that are outside of the 
subdirectory you're filtering on and trees that could be stored as part of commits in the result.

Remember that `filter-branch` is completely rewriting your history - the output is an entirely new set of commits, and there aren't any "linkages" to the old commits, so any extra information has to be expressible as part of the new commits.

Comment: That all makes sense to me, but at least in principle I can imagine taking the current set of files in a directory and tracing back the commit history for each one, counting renames.  In this way, every commit object either involves or does not involve the files in a subdirectory.  Those that don't involve them could be dropped, and those that do could be rewritten to leave out the other files.  

I don't mind having a move commit at the tip of my history, I just want to keep all the changes on the way.

Comment: If you were to `git checkout` one of the "earlier history" commits in your submodule, what would `git` do? If the file used to be "above" what is now the top level directory of the repository, there's no good way for Git to handle that.

Comment: I burned a bunch of time on this to no avail... I still think it can be done by someone of sufficient cleverness though.

Comment: Too bad, since it loses some history this way (if a rename of the folder itself occurred :| ) :|

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I *just* solved a similar problem.  I had started a project in a quasi-private "misc" repository, renamed some files, and then I wanted to upload the project to GitHub at https://github.com/kragen/aikidraw.

```
$ git clone misc aikidraw
$ cat > aikidraw-wanted
aikidraw.js
aikidraw.html
caposketchra.html
caposketchra.js
jquery-1.2.6.js
^D
$ cd aikidraw
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'bash -c "comm -23 <(/bin/ls | sort) <(sort ~/devel/aikidraw-wanted) | xargs rm -rf"' HEAD
```

That seems to have worked okay so far, aside from not deleting dotfiles (like `.git`, good, and `.gitignore`, bad) but apparently my version of Git (1.6.0.4) doesn't have `git filter-branch --prune-empty`.  So now I clone the new, smaller repo (in order to make it faster to copy it over the network) and copy the repo to another machine that has Git 1.7.2.5 on it:

```
$ time git clone aikidraw aikidraw-smaller
$ du -sh aikidraw/.git aikidraw-smaller/.git
8.6M    aikidraw/.git
1.2M    aikidraw-smaller/.git

$ time rsync -Pav aikidraw-smaller panacea.canonical.org:devel/aikidraw/
real    1m23.251s
```

And then on panacea.canonical.org:

```
$ cd ~/devel/aikidraw/aikidraw-smaller  # Oops. I hate rsync sometimes.
$ git checkout  # otherwise I get "Cannot rewrite branch(es) with a dirty working directory."
$ git filter-branch --prune-empty HEAD
$ cd ../..
$ mv aikidraw i-hate-rsync
$ mv i-hate-rsync/aikidraw-smaller/ aikidraw
```

Then back on my netbook:

```
$ mv aikidraw aikidraw-big
$ git clone panacea.canonical.org:devel/aikidraw
$ du -sh aikidraw/.git
268K    aikidraw/.git
```

Now, if you were doing this with two directories instead of five files, you might at this point want to rename everything inside the remaining subdirectory into the root of the repository, using `git mv`.  In my case I've already done my renaming.

```
$ git remote add github git@github.com:kragen/aikidraw.git
$ git push github master
```

Hope this helps!